# How to display empty readonly row in DataGrid only for empty ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I overrided DataGrid witn my class KDataGrid (needed some functionality for our purposes).

```
public class KDataGrid : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid { *** }
```

It can be used with any collection with any RecordType (generic type).

Example XAML with simple KDataGrid:

```
<components:KDataGrid
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="ID"
            Binding="{Binding Id}"
            Width="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Code"
            Binding="{Binding Code}"
            Width="130"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</components:KDataGrid>
```

ViewModel contains:

```
public class SomeRecord: BaseRecord
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

public List<SomeRecord> SomeCollection { get; }
```

KDataGrid (DataGrid) is readonly. Because of that standart empty row in bottom of DataGrid not shows.
If collection *SomeCollection* is empty, it's not possible to set focus on DataGrid (for add new record for example).

Easiest way to fix that (as I think) is: display empty row (which is focusable).
But if collection contains at least one row thats not need to display empty row.

Is there any ideas how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solution is simple. 
Thiere is no need to add empty record.
It just need to get focus by clicking on ScrollViewer:

```
public class KDataGrid : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
{
    public KDataGrid()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var scroll = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>();
        if (scroll != null)
        {
            scroll.MouseDown += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                    return;

                Focus();
            };
        }
    }

    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject root) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = child.FindVisualChild<T>();
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any ideas how can I do that ?

If you want to display an empty row in the DataGrid you could add an "empty" 'SomeRecord' object to your 'SomeCollection' in your view model:

```
SomeCollection.Add(new SomeRecord());
```

The other option is to use a Style that sets the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to a CompositeCollection that contains an empty item only when the SomeCollection source property is empty:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SomeCollection}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeCollection.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <local:SomeRecord />
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="130"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In both cases you probably want to change the type of the ID property from long to long? in order for the ID column to be blank instead of displaying 0 which is the default value for a long.